# Zapier trigger that returns file: what is the format of the z.dehydrateFile call?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I am writing a Zapier trigger that will return a file. I understand that my trigger endpoint does not return the contents of the file, but rather a pointer to it.

All the example documentation shows the [JavaScript example](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/files/):

```
var Zap = {
  your_trigger_post_poll: function(bundle) {
    var records = z.JSON.parse(bundle.response.content);
    return _.map(records, function(record) {
      // if you just do url, we'll include any standard authentication headers
      record.file = z.dehydrateFile('https://yoursite.com/files/download/' + record.id);
      return record;
    });
  }
}
```

I am not writing my trigger in JavaScript. I would like to return the data in the correct format, but I can't find any examples of what that should be.

What is the output of `z.dehydrateFile`? Can you provide a JSON example?

Comment: When you say you're not writing the trigger in javacsript, what are you writing it in? That doc describes a web builder app which uses javascript scripting. I don't believe there's other options.

Comment: Either way, your trigger endpoint *does* return the regular file. Zapier does the heavy lifting for turning a regular file into a dehydrated one. No special action is needed on your end.

Comment: I am writing it in Django/python. I am using the web builder to configure everything. My backend just needs to expose the appropriate APIs.

Comment: I would love to see an example the of the JSON that `z.dehydrateFile('https://yoursite.com/files/download/' + record.id)` returns.

Comment: We really just store the url where the file lives and any auth information we need to access it. Dehydrating defers the fetching of the file, but it happens in the same way

Comment: So the JSON response from a call that returns a file should be `{"file":"https://my.server.com/where/to/download/file"}`? How would I specify a name of the file?

Comment: Oh, i was misunderstanding - your server should return the actual file, like https://zapier.com/brand/assets/images/logos/zapier-logo.png. it's got the `Content-Type: image/png` header. like I said, no special action is needed on your part

Comment: I now see how to return a file. My trigger should return the URL at which the file should be retrieved. I got it working. My trigger returns `{"file":"https://my.server.com/where/to/download/file"}`. I also serve the file contents at that URL. The issue I have is the file has a random name. The endpoint that serves the file does set the `content-disposition` header. It seems to be ignored. The docs show that `dehydrateFile` can take an optional `name` param. I would love to see the resulting JSON that such a `dehydrateFile` call returns.

Comment: The Zapier docs are superb. It was a pleasure to build the integration. The only thing that they are missing is examples of return JSON that various endpoints should serve.

Comment: I just figured it out! So Zapier looks at the URL to determine the file name! It ignores the content-disposition header that the URL returns! In my case, I was offering the file dynamically at a unique URL that ends with a UUID. I just realized that the file name that Zapier got was that name!

Comment: awesome, glad you got it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a file form your trigger to Zapier, you need to return the URL where Zapier can access that file as a record named `'file'`.

If you want your trigger to return "converted_csv_file.xlsx" which can be found on your web server, your trigger would return the following JSON:

```
{
  "file": "https://goodgrids.com/converted_spreadsheets/converted_csv_file.xlsx"
}
```

Note that the URL matters. The last part of the URL will be used as the file name. This is normal when serving up static files. However, if your service generates files on the fly, make sure that you have the file name as part of the URL, even if the actual key used to access the file is somewhere else in your URL.

```
{
  "file": "https://goodgrids.com/converted_spreadsheets/9234659832475982372345876/converted_csv_file.xlsx"
}
```

Suggestion to Zapier: Please look at the `Content-Disposition` header returned when reading the file, to see if it contains a `filename`.